# Math operation on objects

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand how can I run simple math manipulations with objects...

For example if I have this objects of Numbers:

```
var numbers = {first:30.00, second:10.00, third:20, fourth:60, fifth:40}
```

How can I run the `if` loop to output only the ones between 40 and 20 for example? This should output 30, 20, 40.

Comment: That's an object, not an array.

Comment: That isn't an array. That's a plain object.

Comment: Sorry, I meant object :/

Comment: Why do you use these property names instead of numeric indices? Is that for a special reason?

Comment: You really should be using an array.  It will make everything easier.

Comment: @xuhon `Object.keys(numbers).reduce((filtered, currKey) => (numbers[currKey] >= 20 && numbers[currKey] <= 40 ? filtered[currKey] = numbers[currKey], filtered), {})`

Comment: Thank you all! You helped me a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, this is not anarray .. this is an object. And here's the solution you're lookingfor:

```
for (let i in numbers) {
    if (numbers[i] >= 20 && numbers[i] <= 40)
        console.log(numbers[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is working, but I was trying to make it with forEach and it didn't work. Perhaps you may know also why? `numbers.forEach(function (el) {

 if (el.numbers >= 20 && el.numbers <= 40)
 console.log(el.numbers);

});`

Comment: forEach will not work because you have an object not an array, please read documentation for more details:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Answer (score 1):

You could filter the keys and map the values.

Used:

- [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) for getting the keys of an object,
- [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), for shorter syntax,
- [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), returns the element, if the return value is truthy,
- [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for getting a value for each element.

  ```js
  var numbers = { first: 30, second: 10, third: 20, fourth: 60, fifth: 40 };

  console.log(Object
      .keys(numbers)
      .filter(k => numbers[k] >= 20 && numbers[k] <= 40)
      .map(k => numbers[k])
  );
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Your code present object instead of array.

Array enclose data with this symbol "[" and close "]":

```
[num1, num2, num3];
```

To answer your question:

```
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
   if(array[i] >= 20 && array[i] <= 40){
      console.log(array[i]);
   }
}
```

If you use object notation you have to use dot notation to get value like:

```
var numbers = {first: 30, second: 40, third: 50}
numbers.first => 30
numbers.second => 40
etc.
```

I hope it is helpful.